# Discord Bot - Responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

If I have a number of responses:
`const exampleResponses = [ "name1", "name2", "name3"];`

But let's say it's thousands of responses, not just three. Is there a way to pull in the responses from another file? As it stands, with thousands of responses it just clogs up my coding file.

Comment: Don't you have to get them _into_ a file first? Please revise to add detail about your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can go about this. One way would be to have a separate file with one array containing all the responses, then export that variable and require it in your main file

**Responses.js**

```
const responses = ['r1', 'r2', 'r3'] 
// And so on...

module.exports = {
   responses
}
```

**Main File**

```
const { responses } = require('filePathToResponsesJS')
```

Answer (score 2):

A way to do this is to make a JSON file and call from it with JavaScript.

```js
const { exampleResponses } = require('./example.json')
```

```json
{
  "exampleResponses": [
    "name1",
    "name2",
    "name3"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import the FileSystem module and do something like this:

```
responses= JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync( 'data/responses.json', function( err, data ) { ... }
```

Similarly, you can write to said file to keep things neat and tidy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for any naivety (I'm still so new to this) but I add in the FS module with:
```const fs = require('fs');``` 
Is there any other lines I need subsequently to tell the const response where to find the JSON file with all the data inside?